# IOException: Unreachable exception codenameone

Tags: java, java-io, codenameone, ioexception

I used writeObject and readObject to store in storage in order to work in offline mode as well
but when there is no network connection, it gives unreachable exception. Most of the time, it doesnt
affect the app but some time, the app doesnt function. I have to close the app and then restart to make it 
work.

exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Unreachable
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.connect(JavaSEPort.java:5355)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.connect(JavaSEPort.java:5387)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:299)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:263)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

code:

```
void galleryCategoryOfflineStorage(Form f) {
        Vector galleryVectorRead = (Vector) Storage.getInstance().readObject("galleryCategory");
        connectionForGallery(f);
        if (galleryVectorRead != null) {
            galleryVector = galleryVectorRead;
        }
        if (galleryVector != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < galleryVector.size(); j++) {
                Hashtable hm = (Hashtable) galleryVector.get(j);
                String categoryId = (String) hm.get("category_id");
                String categoryName = (String) hm.get("category_name");
                String categoryIcon = (String) hm.get("image_url");

                String name = categoryIcon.substring(categoryIcon.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, categoryIcon.lastIndexOf("."));
                placeholder = placeholder.scaledEncoded((screenWidth / 2) - 5, (screenWidth / 2) - 5);
                Image icon = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "beckk" + name, categoryIcon, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);

                Container categoryContainer = new Container();
                Button categoryButton = new Button();
                categoryButton.setText(categoryName);
                categoryButton.setTextPosition(Label.BOTTOM);
                categoryButton.setUIID("categoryButton");
                categoryButton.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                categoryButton.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
                categoryButton.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xcccccc);
                categoryButton.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createBevelLowered());
                categoryContainer.addComponent(categoryButton);

                categoryButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
                    showGalleryImagesList(categoryId);
                });
                f.addComponent(j, categoryContainer);
                f.setScrollableY(true);
                f.revalidate();
            }
        }
    }
```

myConnection:

```
public void connectionForGallery(Form f) {
        galleryNoConnectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                results = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
                galleryVector = (Vector<Map<String, Object>>) results.get("root");
//                System.out.println("galleryVector " + galleryVector);
            }

            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
                Storage.getInstance().writeObject("galleryCategory", galleryVector);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                Dialog.show("Error msg", "The server returned the error code: " + code, "ok", null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleException(Exception err) {
                Dialog.show("Connection msg", "There was a connection error: " + err, "ok", null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleIOException(IOException err) {
                Dialog.show("IO exception", "There was a IO error: " + err, "ok", null);
            }
        };

        galleryNoConnectionRequest.setPost(false);
        galleryNoConnectionRequest.setUrl("http://myUrl");
        galleryNoConnectionRequest.setDuplicateSupported(true);
        InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
        Dialog dialog = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
        galleryNoConnectionRequest.setDisposeOnCompletion(dialog);
        galleryNoConnectionRequest.setFailSilently(true);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(galleryNoConnectionRequest);
    }
```

Moreover there is `handleIOException()` method in the `connectionRequest` class as above but it doesnt handle `IOException: Unreachable` exception.

Also there is `handleErrorResponseCode()` method as well but if there is no connection, it doesn't respond too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope 
galleryNoConnectionRequest.settimeout(30000); 
will work.

Answer (score -1):

A host is unreachable if your network is problematic. From your other question I understand that this is a general networking issue you are experiencing.

If your network is unreliable you need to catch the exceptions/errors and handle them correctly.

Comment: why can't handleIOException(), handleErrorResponseCode(), handleException() method of ConnectionRequest class handle them? If not how can i handle them separately? Actually my other question isnt related to this. That is of webBrowser issue and this exception occurs only when there is no network connection problem.

Comment: Simple, the exception you are seeing is for a different connection. Not for the fail silently connection request. E.g. are you downloading images or something?

Comment: no i am not downloading, jst a urlImage caches as above connection

Comment: `URLImage` fails silently too. Open the `NetworkMonitor` and see the specific URL request that triggers this.